# Rails Group_By Limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am following this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month

and have built a system to allow a user to assign a contact to a specific label. However I need pagination such that it only returns the first 3 labels, second 3 labels, etc.

How do I go about doing this in ActiveRecord

```
def index
    @connections = @current_user.user_contacts.where('label_id > 0').order("updated_at")
    @connections_label = @connections.group_by { |t| t.label_id }
end

Contact Table
ID | Name | Label_ID
01 | Mike | 1

Label Table
ID | Name
1  | PSU
```

**UPDATED**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `take`

What are you using for pagination? If you wanted to print this out in erb, it would be something like this.

```
<%= @connections.group_by { |t| t.label_id }.take(3).each do |label, connections| %>
  <%= label.name %>
  <% connections.each do |connection|
    <%= connection.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This would give you the first 3 labels:

```
Label 1
 Mike
 ...

Label 2
 Bob
 ...

Label 3
 Jim
 ...
```

In your controller you should be able to something like @VVN suggested:

```
.take(3).offset((params[page] || 0) * 3)
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

try to use

```
@connections_label = @connections.group("label_id").limit(3).offset((params[page] || 0) * 3)
```

or you can

```
@connection_labels = @connections.user_contacts.group(:label_id).map(&:label).uniq

@labels_separated_by_3 = []
@connection_labels.each_with_index do |cl, index|
  @labels_separated_by_3[index / 3] ||= []
  @labels_separated_by_3[index / 3] << cl
end
```

and you will get array of arrays with labels. like this:

```
1.9.2-p290 :033 > @connection_labels = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c']
1.9.2-p290 :034 > @labels_separated_by_3 = []
 => [] 
1.9.2-p290 :035 > @connection_labels.each_with_index do |cl, index|
1.9.2-p290 :036 >     @labels_separated_by_3[index / 3] ||= []
1.9.2-p290 :037?>     @labels_separated_by_3[index / 3] << cl
1.9.2-p290 :038?> end
 => ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c"] 
1.9.2-p290 :039 > @labels_separated_by_3
 => [["a", "a", "a"], ["b", "b", "b"], ["c", "c"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if I'm not understanding you properly. What it seems like you are looking for is a limiter? Limiting the tasks returned to those due or created within the last 3 months?

Something like this:

```
@tasks = Task.where("created_at > ?", 3.months.ago)
@task_months = @tasks.group_by { |t| t.due_at.beginning_of_month }
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: in this scenario that would 100% work. I actually simplified the problem for this post thinking it would be easier to relate. I have updated my question to my exact problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`limit` and `offset` methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset), right?

```
@connections_label = @connections.group_by { |t| t.label_id }.limit(3).offset(3)
```

Comment: that is essentially what I am trying to do. However I get "undefined method `limit'" when trying this

Comment: @MikeSilvis are you using rails 3?

Comment: Ah, I see, the `group_by` method you are using is returning a Hash. Try with `group(:label_id)`

Comment: okay. Now this will run if I use @connections.group(:label_id, "contacts.id")

However for some reason this is not Grouping by the :label_id so I'm not sure what it is doing. It is probably important to note that I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: Well, you are now using the SQL grouping, not the Hash grouping. They work quite different. You will only see one connection per label_id and contact id. You can find the SQL query in the log or the console, and run it directly in PostgreSQL to see what the db is returning.